# Add column/cell with class to table based on first cell text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following table...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
         <tr class="trclass">
             <td class="tdclass">Test1</td>
             <td class="tdclass">Test2</td>
             <td class="tdclass">Test3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="trclass">
             <td class="tdclass">Test4</td>
             <td class="tdclass">Test5</td>
             <td class="tdclass">Test6</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I add a cell to each row in between (test2 and test3) and (test5 and test6) with a class based on text from the first cells (test1 and test4)? Basically to look like this...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="trclass">
            <td class="tdclass">Test1</td>
            <td class="tdclass">Test2</td>
            <td class="Test1">NewText</td>
            <td class="tdclass">Test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trclass">
            <td class="tdclass">Test4</td>
            <td class="tdclass">Test5</td>
            <td class="Test4">NewText</td>
            <td class="tdclass">Test6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried things like

```
jQuery(".tdclass").after("<td>test</td>");
```

and

```
jQuery(".tdclass").append("<td>test</td>");
```

but I'm not sure how to loop and achieve this exact scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$("tr.trclass").each(function() {
   var className = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
   $(this).find("td:eq(1)").after("<td class=" + className + ">NewText</td>");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ECu36/

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easy to control by css attribute as follows:

```
$('tr.trclass').find('td:nth-child(2)').after('<td>testing123</td>');
```